# Error writing to file c: windows\syswow64\mfc100.dll during installation of SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server-2014

During installation of SQL Server 2014 there is error appears **Error writing to file c: windows\syswow64\mfc100.dll verify that you've access to that directory** as you can see below image, 
[image]

I navigate to that directory and not found mfc100.dll file as you can see below, 
[image]

How can i resolve this issue kindly help

Comment: The file wasn't in the said directory, the setup program was just trying to copy it there and failed. It showed your the error because it failed. And you can't find the file in the directory also because it failed. That's just to explain the error message, which, I agree, might be a tiny bit confusing. I'm afraid I don't have the answer to the question *why* it failed. Hopefully someone will come up with a good one.

Comment: thanks for guidance. But still have this problem. I'm also trying and trying since yesterday

Comment: Looks like that file is part of the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package. Do you still get this error after a restart of the OS ? Try pre-installing these packages, restart, and start the SQL install again: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555 and https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14632

Comment: You can also search for more details on the error by opening the setup log as described: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/view-and-read-sql-server-setup-log-files?view=sql-server-2014

Comment: During installation of Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86) it again gives error for Error writing file for mfc140.dll

Comment: @RazvanZoitanu During installation of Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86) it again gives error for Error writing file for mfc140.dll

Comment: What version of Windows do you have? It would be best if you could post the SQL setup log to pastebin.com and provide the link here, I might be able to replicate the error on my lab with this information.

Comment: For the 140 error try the 2015 version of the redist: https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=48145 Also make sure you run Windows Update and restart before retrying the SQL setup.

Comment: @RazvanZoitanu again gives error for 2015 ---------------------------
Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x86) - 14.0.23026 Setup
---------------------------
Error 1310.Error writing to file: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mfc140.dll.   Verify that you have access to that directory.
---------------------------
Retry   Cancel   
---------------------------